# Metro UI breadcrumb guidelines / examples?

Tags: breadcrumbs, metro

Are there any guidelines for, or examples of breadcrumbs in metro UI applications? Especially for applications that have a deep hierarchical structure.

Edit: I'm not looking for guidelines on how many levels of hierarchy windows allows me to have.

Answer (score 1):

The Metro guideline allows for three levels of hierarchy in a native app i.e.

1. The Hub page
2. Specific category page
3. The sub category page.

If you are designing your app, you are expected to ensure all your data is accessible within these three levels of hierarchy but however you could use actions such as filters to drill down into specific categories to simplify the access.

With regards to web based apps,you can use bread crumbs in the website as needed

Remember Metro is a design language but its not expected to completely overhaul basic design principles and design patterns

Comment: I am familiar with the three level hierarchy guideline but my application is not going to fit in three levels. Also the three level guideline does not have breadcrumbs.